# How can I preserve line breaks in bash when comparing output to regex?

Tags: regex, bash, newline, cat

If I have the following code:

```
if [[ "$(cat myfile)" =~ ^scripts\/.* ]]; then
  echo YES
else
  echo NO
fi
```

And "myfile" contains the following:

```
hot/warm
scripts/whatever
cold/cool
```

The result when I run my code is "NO", but I want it to be YES.

If I change "myfile" by re-ordering the contents so that "scripts/whatever" comes first, like below:

```
scripts/whatever
hot/warm
cold/cool
```

Then the result when I run my script is indeed YES. This is problematic because I want my script to detect whether that regex pattern occurs on any line of the contents, not just the first.

Comment: Why not just use `grep -q '^scripts/.*$' myfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition:

```
[[ "$(cat myfile)" =~ ^scripts\/.* ]];
```

is checking for regex on complete file data (that you extract using `cat myfile` command), hence it will only match when file content starts with `scripts/`.

It is not matching every line start.

For that you can just use `grep` with your `git diff` command (see comments below):

```
if git diff | grep -q '^scripts/'; then
  echo 'YES'
else
  echo 'NO'
fi
```

Comment: I used `cat myfile` as an example, but really I plan on executing a `git diff` command instead of having a real file to grep through.

Comment: If you are using `git diff` then use `git diff | grep -q 'scripts/`

Comment: Thanks, I think you still left in "myfile" in the answer with the git diff code block by mistake, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using grep you can use a while-read-do loop as follows.

```
cat myfile | while read LINE; do
  if [[ "$LINE" =~ ^scripts\/.* ]]; then
    echo YES
  else
    echo NO
  fi
done
```

I ran this on the two versions of the file you posted and got the following output (in the same order as you posted them):

```
YES
NO
NO
```

AND

```
NO
YES
NO
```

The only thing about this is that it will print once per line in the file, so you probably want to use a [break](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html) in the YES condition if you only want to print once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that "scripts" appears at the beginning of the *string* **or** at the beginning of *a line*, then do this:

```
[[ "$(< myfile)" =~ (^|$'\n')scripts/.* ]]
```

Notes

- you don't need to escape the slash in a bash regex
- `$(< file)` is a bash builtin way to do `$(cat file)`

In this case using grep as anubhava demonstrates is probably more clear and faster.